# What are the possible data access layer design-patterns for desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, design-patterns

What are the possible data access layer design-patterns for c# applications ?

Any advice will be useful.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055710/data-access-layer-design-patterns

Comment: Learn how to ask specific questions, please. Your question would take years to asnwer listing ALL POSSIBLE (!) layers, regardless whether they make sense or not. Voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the question being somewhat broad, you might find Spring.NET's [DAO support](http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/dao.html) helpful (particularly the [ADO chapter](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/ado.html)).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of data access layer design-patterns are described [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420). 3 tier architecture with data mapping is widely spread