# Design pattern to enable replacement of underlying database at later date, with minimal efforts

Tags: design-patterns

What pattern should be used to ensure the database software is completely replaceable (at a later date) with minimal effort.

This is for a brand new application.

Thanks!

Comment: You may find the following post helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055710/data-access-layer-design-patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ones that pop into my mind first are the [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) patterns. I would recommend finding an implementation in your language of choice for whatever abstraction layer you choose. If you're considering writing your own version, take into account the time to implement vs. picking an off the shelf solution

Answer (score 0):

For entity mapping you need a class that maps your entities to the database in the most simple way, using a [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) or [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).
You must also implement an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) to handle database initialization, connection creation and all that stuff.