# Architecture for iphone app with facebook connect

Tags: iphone, ios, design-patterns, architecture

I'm working on an iphone app and i would like to seek advices on what's the best architecture for it.

Basically, the app implements facebook connect for users to login. Users will be able to select their friends whom they can message/send photos to (think of whatsapp). I will have a server which i intend to use to store their sent messages and photos. Whats's the best way to separate the components? And also, should the logic that deals with sending data to my server and reading from it know anything about the facebook connect componenet?

Does anyone has any ideas on whats the best architecture for such an app?

Comment: Nice question, but could you give an example of an architecture to address what you are proposing?

Comment: I'm agree with @darlinton, great question. That Guy, did you find out what architecture fits your app best?

Answer (score 0):

Compartmentalizing data access is a widely accepted practice and in your case, data access is:

- Connecting to FB
- Connecting to your database server

Ideally your domain logic shouldn't know where it is getting data from (web service, database, FB, G+, etc).  All it should know is that it is getting data, and what it should do with that data.

Some common patterns that address abstracting your data access layer from your domain layer are:

- [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)
- [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

The above links are to Martin Fowler's blog, but some searching around google or stackoverflow should yield additional clarity:

- [Data Access Layer Design Patters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055710/data-access-layer-design-patterns)
- [Microsoft Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx), but relevant to any modern OOP language (even mentions ruby).